# jeep compass 2012 with 4wd locker on, only one rear wheel spins

Tags: jeep, 4wd, differential, traction-control

With my Jeep Compass 2012 when 4wd locker is on (I see it ON on the panel as I pulled locker),

So I noticed that when I was parking at full of now parking lot, my front wheels stopped spinning, and only one rear wheel keep spinning (with no much traction) so I stack and had to shovel... (which is silly for that car). The surface itself is horizontal (not a hill, just parking lot next to my house)

I expected that all 4 wheels would be at work trying to get through the snow to get traction (since I "locked it" to be 4wd)

I do not have any warning message on my board.

Q: How to make all 4 wheels do their job? (maybe my 4wd is broken but it does not show it)

Answer (score 3):

In a situation like this, my Landrover Discovery 2 uses the traction control system to pulse the brakes on the wheels that are spinning faster than the others (described simply).  In so doing, it transfers torque to the other wheels which should then cause all 4 wheels to turn.

I would presume that your vehicle should be doing a similar thing, especially since it is a lot newer vehicle.  Do you have any known problem with the traction control system?  Is it turned on?

Comment: i guess now i have to ask/google how to turn it off/on ). I have ESC button on my board: looks like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_stability_control#/media/File:Kontrollleuchte_ESP_2_black.svg but there is no difference whether it is on or off  for my case I described. But I have no warning lights at all

Comment: Try holding the button down for more than 5 seconds.